# How do you copy/paste HTML code in Google Web Designer?

Tags: google-web-designer

How do you cut and paste HTML code ***(code view)*** in Google Web Designer?

Tried copy paste with notepad but that doesn't work.

I am using version 1.3.0.0410 beta, but an answer that works across all version would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy and paste code within Google Web Designer's Code View by using the standard keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Control/Command</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for cut, +<kbd>C</kbd> for copy, +<kbd>V</kbd> for paste), or by right-clicking on selected text and using the context menu that appears.

You should also be able to use the corresponding options under the *Edit* menu. However, these are currently not working due to a bug.

<sup>Disclosure: I am an engineer on the Google Web Designer team.</sup>